# How to rewrite doubles only for odd index except uppermost row with odd and keep all doubles with even index

Tags: c#

how to rewrite all duplicate lines in my text document, but only if duplicate line has odd index number and keep only one with odd which is above the all in order and keep all duplicates with even indexes.

For example with content:

```
01. line1
02. line2
03. line3    <-- keep this with odd index because it is first in order  
04. line4
05. line5
06. line6
07. line3    <-- rewrite this double because it is not first with odd index
08. line8
09. line9
10. line3    <-- keep this double, because line  index is even number 
11. line11 
12. line3    <-- keep this double, because line  index is even number 
13. line3    <-- rewrite this double
14. line3    <-- keep this double, because line  index is even number
```

Comment: What does the actual text file look like? Does it contain the '>' and index number? What do you want to put in place of the duplicates?  I don't understand what 'rewrite' means.

Comment: @jdweng text document contains only lines phrases, I put numbers above just to explain, so I guess index number can be asked  this way `if (index % 2 == 0)`. and I want   just replace asked lines  with "X" for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> uniqueOddLines = new List<string>();
            List<string> lines = new List<string>();
            string inputLine = "";
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            int index = 0;
            while ((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                inputLine = inputLine.Trim();
                if (++index % 2 == 0)
                {
                    lines.Add(inputLine);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (uniqueOddLines.Contains(inputLine))
                    {
                        lines.Add(string.Format("Rewrite line {0}", index));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        uniqueOddLines.Add(inputLine);
                        lines.Add(inputLine);
                    }
                }

            }

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your looking for help on writing the logic not reading and writing your file. Therefore, for simplicity I will answer the question assuming an array as input and using the indices in place of the line numbers.

```
public void CleanFile(string[] lines) {
    var oddLines = new HashSet<String>();
    for(int i = 1; i <= lines.Length; i += 2) {
        if(!oddLines.Add(lines[i]) {
            lines[i] = //whatever your rewriting it with
        }
    }
}
```