# Replace found line in text document

Tags: c#

I got this code, which finds doubles with odd indexes to replace all with "X" except first one with odd index but keeps all doubles with even indexes. Question is how to  replace found line in text document. This way I got result which must be replaced but  how to overwrite lines in text document

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = "test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> uniqueOddLines = new List<string>();
            List<string> lines = new List<string>();
            string inputLine = "X";
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            int index = 0;
            while ((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                inputLine = inputLine.Trim();
                if (++index % 2 == 0)
                {
                    lines.Add(inputLine);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (uniqueOddLines.Contains(inputLine))
                    {
                        lines.Add(string.Format("Rewrite line {0}", index));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        uniqueOddLines.Add(inputLine);
                        lines.Add(inputLine);
                    }
                }    
            }   
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

For example content in text document is:

```
row1
row2
row3 
row4
row5
row6
row3 
row8
row9
row3 
row11 
row3 
row3 
row3
```

work of given code:

```
01. row1
02. row2
03. row3 <- keep row with odd index because it is first in order  
04. row4
05. row5
06. row6
07. row3 <- rewrite this double because it is not the first one with odd index
08. row8
09. row9
10. row3 <- keep this double, because row index is even number 
11. row11 
12. row3 <- keep this double, because row index is even number 
13. row3 <- rewrite this double because it is not the first one with odd index
14. row3 <- keep this double, because row index is even number
```

And here is desired result, same as above, but I want it in text document:

```
row1
row2
row3 
row4
row5
row6
X
row8
row9
row3 
row11 
row3 
X
row3
```

Comment: Could you, please, provide an example of initial data and expected output?

Comment: You cant overwrite particular lines in a text document, you have to overwrite the whole document. Luckily you already have the desired content in the `lines`. Just write it to a file with the same name.

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko done I've edited it above

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245243/delete-specific-line-from-a-text-file

Comment: same homework, same code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39323412/how-to-rewrite-doubles-only-for-odd-index-except-uppermost-row-with-odd-and-keep/39323852#39323852

Comment: @Slai got it thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using *Linq*: `ReadLines` will return the file lines and `Select` is convenient to implement the logic within:

```
const string FILENAME = "test.txt";

// Side effect (adding into the set while selecting) is very convenient in the context,
// but should be implemented with care 
HashSet<String> appeared = new HashSet<String>();

var result = File
  .ReadLines(FILENAME)
   // index % 2 == 0 since index is zero-based
  .Select((line, index) => !appeared.Add(line.Trim()) && (index % 2 == 0) 
     ? "X"
     : line)
  .ToList(); // materialization, in case you want both Console and File 

foreach (var line in result)
  Console.WriteLine(line);

Console.ReadLine();
```

In case you want to write the lines back to file as well as onto console:

```
File.WriteAllLines(FILENAME, result);
```

Comment: .hello, this way I got different result 
`row1
row2
row3 
row4
row5
row6
row3
row8
row9
X
row11 
X
row3
X`

and in document I got this:
`line1
X
line3 
X
line5
X
line3
X
line9
X
line11
X
line3
X`

Comment: @zrubi: sorry, it should be `(index % 2 == 0)`, see my edit

Comment: not sure what I'm doing wrong,  I got absolutely correct result with your code on console, but in the text document, no matter write to new file of into the same (I need same)  I got  this result again `X
row2
X
row4
X
row6
X
row8
X
row3
X
row3
X
row3`

Comment: @zrub: it seems that you want the output both on console and file; in that case materialize *before* any output (move `ToList` to be after select); see my edit

Comment: exactly, that's what I want, big support